# Raspberry Pi 4 output python if else results to LCD: Random characters

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to make a simple python script that uses a moisture sensor on GOIP 21 and will output text on a display.

What I have:

- Raspberry Pi 4 4GB
- [Arducam 1602 16x2 LCD Display Module Based on HD44780](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019D9TYMI)
- [KeeYees 5 Pcs High Sensitivity Soil Moisture Sensor Module with Female to Female Jump Wires, Sensor Module Watering System Manager for Arduino TE215](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QXZC8TQ)
- [Breadboard 830](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H7V1X7Y)

It's only a learning attempt, after I figure this out I plan on buying better sensors and actually having them display accurate percentages. For not a simple moisture detected vs no-detected is okay with me.

My code seems to work for outputting to the console, however when I try to output to the LCD, it gives some weird characters and stops. Not sure what to do as i'm not a python wiz (you'd think id be more like php, but nah lol).

Here is my code

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/lcd')
import lcd

#GPIO SETUP
moist1 = 21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(moist1, GPIO.OUT)
def callback(moist1):
        if GPIO.input(moist1):
                lcd.GPIO.cleanup()
                lcd.lcd_init()
                lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_1, lcd.LCD_CMD)
                lcd.lcd_string("Water Is Good", 2)
                lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
                lcd.lcd_string("Don't Add", 2)
                lcd.GPIO.cleanup()
        else:
                lcd.GPIO.cleanup()
                lcd.lcd_init()
                lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_1, lcd.LCD_CMD)
                lcd.lcd_string("Add Water Now!", 2)
                lcd.lcd_byte(lcd.LCD_LINE_2, lcd.LCD_CMD)
                lcd.lcd_string("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", 2)
                lcd.GPIO.cleanup()

GPIO.add_event_detect(moist1, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)  # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW
GPIO.add_event_callback(moist1, callback)  # assign function to GPIO PIN, Run function on change

# infinite loop
while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please let me know if you see it. Thanks

Comment: You probably shouldn't call cleanup and init for the LCD that many times...

Comment: @AKX is there a reason? Just wondering cause i honestly don't know. I figured, call a clear after and before, is that not right?

Comment: I think `cleanup()` will clean up resources related to the LCD, not clear the screen.